# How to hide box on body click except of button in using ReactJS Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

T have a button with a box & box will hide/show (toggle) on button click. This is working fine now I want to when we click on body except of button then box should be hide.

My Code:-

```js
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (
<div>
<button className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}></button>
  {show ? <div className="box"></div>
  : null}
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

ThankYou for your efforts!

Comment: Are you still have problem?

Comment: no its solved now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many tricks to solve this. But one of them I prefer, do it like modals. So:

1. Add background div beside of the `box` that shows back of the box
2. Set onClick on this new div to hide the box

```
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

 return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}></button>
        {show && (
        <>
          <div style={{bottom:0 , top:0, right:0, left:0,position:"absolute"}} onClick={()=> setShow(false)}></div>
          <div className="box"></div>
        </>) 
        }
      </div>
      );

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your point rightly. You can solve it like this.
It will close the box/modal when one clicks outside of the modal or body

```js
function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (
<div>
<button className="btn" onClick={() => setShow(!show)}></button>
  {show ? 
<div onClick={() => setShow(false)} 
 style={{width: '100vw',
         height: '100vh', 
         position: 'absolute', 
         top: 0, 
         left: 0
 }}> 
  <div className="box" onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}></div>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```